# Accessing docker container websocket through nginx or traefik via html web page?

Tags: docker, nginx, websocket, docker-compose, traefik

I have two docker containers running - one has a websocket and the other is an nginx container. Setup using `docker-compose.yml` as follows:

```
version: "3.5"

  websocket: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "6000:7000"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "120:80"
```

In my `index.html` in the nginx container, I currently have to set `socketUrl: "http://192.168.X.X:6000",`i.e. the local IP address for the websocket container.

Is there a way of setting up nginx so that `socketUrl: "http://websocket:7000"`? Either using nginx or traefik?

If I run on different machines I have to manually edit the `socketUrl` for the new machine. I'd like the setup to be standard across machines so that I can access the websocket via html at http://192.168.X.X:120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use links to access the other container via hostname:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  websocket: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: websocket
    ports: 
      - "6000:7000"

  nginx:
    image: dperson/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "120:80"
    environment:
      - STREAM=0.0.0.0:80;websocket:7000
    links:
      - websocket
```

if this doesn't work, force them to be on the same network:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  websocket: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: websocket
    ports: 
      - "6000:7000"
    networks:
      - default

  nginx:
    image: dperson/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "120:80"
    environment:
      - STREAM=0.0.0.0:80;websocket:7000
    links:
      - websocket
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
```

Comment: Just tried these options, but neither work. When I open the browser there's no connection to the websocket. I've put `http://websocket:7000` in the `index.html` is that correct?

Comment: oh, that's not how it's done. only the nginx container knows the websocket hostname, not the remote client who is requesting the index.html. that's why you have to route remote requests internally over a reverse nginx/traefik http proxy (or stream like in my sample) can you be more specific what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I suspected it wasn't the right way. I'm trying to send messages to/from a websocket server (hosted in a container) through an index.html. The system works with a browser on the host by adding "http://localhost:6000" . I'm stuck when it comes to the proxy.

Comment: The websocket port has to be accessible from the remote client who requests the index.html (public port 6000). So just make the port public and forge the url with javascript's [location.hostname](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_hostname) because the remote websocket hostname (the machine who hosts these containers) would be the same as from the nginx container. If you want to keep the websocket private, you would have to route it through a backend, like php